# Good way of displaying form validation errors in php as input placeholder without Javascript

Tags: php, css, forms, focusout

I'm trying to display errors on form validation as the placeholder in the input box.

Right now I have this HTML/PHP code:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter first name"
class="<?php if(isset($error['name'])){echo "error-found";} else { echo "no-error";} ?>"
value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES); } ?>" tabindex="1">
```

and CSS:

```
.error-found[type=text]:focus{
    color: inherit;
}
.error-found[type=text]{
    color:red;
}
```

When error is found the color of the placeholder text changes to red. When user goes to the input box and writes something it turns to inherit color but when user goes to the next box / on focus out, the color changes to red again, which is not what I want.

Is there a way through PHP/CSS/HTML, without using Javascript to have the color not change to red on focus out and only if text is entered in the input box ?

Comment: Not unless you can find some other way to change the css class

Comment: I'm on it but only found a few ways through Javascript on focusout. Would applying some other css class with !important at the end make it happen ?

Comment: But how can that be possible without Javascript ?

Comment: That was my point, I dont know of another way without javascript

Comment: bummer, Javascript it is then !

Answer (score 0):

Did you try below CSS script?

```
.error-found[type=text]:not(:focus){
    color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Tried it but it's skipping the red and taking the inherit for both focus and not focus.

Comment: isn't ‘.error-found[type=text]{color:red!}”

the same as :

.error-found[type=text]:not(:focus){color: inherit;}

???

Comment: I was just trying out of the box(without JS involvement) to achieve your request but available option is to use only JavaScript which could save time. Those mentioned two CSS script does same job and there is no much different in the output.